# WordPress | Woocommerce add_link_to_product_page - for a specific category only

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i've inherited a site & someone has created a plugin to add a subscribe button to single products, which simply links to a separate page.
it's currently appearing on all products, however the client only wants this button/link to appear on products belonging to a specific category.
i know this is a simple change, for anyone but me.
can anyone point me in the right direction here?
product-category/wine or, taxonomy=product_cat&tag_ID=45
here's the code:

```
function add_link_to_product_page(  ) { 
    global $product;
    if( !$product->is_type( 'grouped' ) ) {
        echo'<a class="button single_add_to_cart_button" href="' . get_permalink(1073) . '">Subscribe</a>';
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'add_link_to_product_page', 10, 0 ); 
?>
```

many, many thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use has_term() function. please check below code.

```
function add_link_to_product_page() {
    global $product;
    if( !$product->is_type( 'grouped' ) && has_term( 45, 'product_cat' ) ) {
        echo'<a class="button single_add_to_cart_button" href="' . get_permalink(1073) . '">Subscribe</a>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'add_link_to_product_page', 10, 0 );
```

Comment: brilliant, super simple - will give that a shot, thank you Bhautik